# iterable : Can I start iteration from the start again after .next value?

Tags: javascript

So here is the problem

```
let iterable = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
iterator.next(); // { value: 'a', done: false }
```

Can I start iteration again from start or have to reinitialize `iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]()` again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `Iterator` interface](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iterator-interface) does not expose any method to rewind the position (not to say that in general not every iteration is rewindable), so the answer is "no".

You must create another iterator to get the first value once again.